# Crear bucle script bash si se cumple una condición

Tags: bash

Estoy iniciándome en el scripting de bash y no consigo lo que pretendo.
Tengo el código que muestro a continuación y mi intención es que si la condición del if (if [[ $med_pausa >  1 ]]) se cumple el scritp se relance desde el principio. El código no es muy limpio pero intento ir esquivando los problemas como sé.

```bash
#/bin/bash
    
#Verificar si hay algún media server pausado.
    
    
#Obtenenmos el estado de todos los medias
./nbemmcmd -listhosts -verbose | egrep -i '(MachineName|MachineState)' > /tmp/meida_state.txt
    
times=$rept
#Buscamos que activos están desactivados
cat /tmp/meida_state.txt | grep -B1 "administrative pause" > /tmp/mediaserver_pause.txt
    
#Contar lineas
med_pausa=$(cat /tmp/mediaserver_pause.txt | wc -l)
dev=$"2"
rept=$((( $med_pausa / $dev )))
    
#Sacamos variable con nombre del media server
cat /tmp/mediaserver_pause.txt | awk -F '"' '{print $2}' > /tmp/variable_medserv.txt
    
#Creamos una variable con el nombre del activo desactivado
awk 'NF != 3 { printf "%s", $0; getline; gsub("\n", "") } 1' /tmp/variable_medserv.txt > /tmp/media.txt
med=$(awk 'NR==1' /tmp/media.txt)
    
    
if [[ $med_pausa >  1 ]]
then
    ./nbemmcmd -updatehost -machinename $med -machinestateop clr_admin_pause -machinetype media -masterserver media_server_03
    rm -f /tmp/variable_medserv.txt
    sleep 3m
else
    echo " No hay medias desactivados"
fi
```

Comment: Al margen de la confusión que puede dar el doble corchete, la comparación de valores con test, en el caso de mayor, sería $med_pausa -gt 1. Revisa el man del comando "test"

Comment: Buenas, he revisado el comando test y con esto es mejor pero el problema que tengo todavía es que no relanza el scritp si el test -s da 0

Comment: @Jakala, ni el comando test `test` ni el builtin `test` son lo mismo que el builtin `[[` aunque pueden tener similitudes. Además, el `man` de `test` sería el del programa, no el del actual builtin `test`. Al inicio en Bash es medio engorroso sabe que no es lo mismo un programa que un builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El signo `>` tiene un significado especial en bash (redirección); no es un operador de comparación aritmética. Utiliza

```
if [[ "$med_pausa" -gt  1 ]]
then
...
fi
```

Comment: No necesariamente. Dentro del builtin `[[`, los signos `<>` ordenan lexicográficamente. Fuera del builtin si es lo que dices. `When used with [[, the < and > operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.`